# Office 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, office-2007

Amongst the swamp of documentation that is MSDN there is not an article to be found about the latest and greatest tools to be used in conjunction with Office 2007, specifically in the "VBA" department.

We've been using old school versions of Office for many years and had to use VBA.  Upgrading to Office 2007 was a prospect for the PDF tools, however ye olde VBA seems to be the only choice of development within it.

Are there not newer .NET tools available? VB.NET, or C#.NET at least?  If I have to declare and assign variables on separate lines using VBA one more time I think I may pluck my nose hairs out due to sheer frustration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTO or [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx)